# in need of a php preg_replace regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am writing a script that needs to download images related to a product ID array to an external website.
Here are the possible product ID combinations.

- ABC1234AB
- ABC1234AB-CD
- ABC1234AB-CDE
- ABC1234ABC

I need to be able to convert them to their URL equivalent on the manufacturer's website, which are (In the same order):

- abc1234_ab
- abc1234_ab_cd
- abc1234_ab_cde
- abc1234_abc

I am looking for a Regex to use with preg_replace that would do the trick.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = strtolower(preg_replace('~\d\K(?=[A-Z])|-~', '_', $input));
```

`\K` removes that is matched on the left from the match result, so , the digit before the letter is not a part of the match and will not be replaced.

`(?=...)` is a [lookahead assertion](http://regular-expressions.com/lookaround.html) that checks if a letter if following, it isn't a part of the match result too and will not be replaced too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob in regular expressions but I`ll give it a shot.

Input:  `/([A-Z]+)\d+([A-Z]+)\-([A-Z]+)/`

A-Z matches uppercase alpha characters
\d matches numbers

"+" is used to repeat

And in the replacement callback use strtolower on the matches and join them how you want :P